# Storing Images in Project Folder - Directory Not Found Error Message

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to save images to a SlideImages folder in my ASP.NET web forms website, using C#.

When I try to submit an image using the following code:

```
 protected void btnSubmitImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get Filename from fileupload control
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileuploadimages.PostedFile.FileName);
    //Save images into SlideImages folder
    fileuploadimages.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("SlideImages/" + filename));

    //Open the database connection
    con7.Open();
    //Query to insert images name and Description into database
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into SlideShowTable(ImageName,Description) values(@ImageName,@Description)", con7);
    //Passing parameters to query



    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageName", filename);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", txtDesc.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //Close dbconnection
    con7.Close();
    txtDesc.Text = string.Empty;
    BindDataList();
}
```

I get the below error message when trying to execute the 4th line of the code above.

> An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\11342\OneDrive\Documents\4th Year\FYP\BallinoraWaterfallCommunity\SlideImages\'.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg1ba.png) is my project folder structure. I am trying to store the images in the SlideImages folder of my project.

I managed to successfully store images in the 'Images' folder using the below code. I have tried to adapt it to fix the above problem, but I have not been able to.

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get Filename from fileupload control
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileuploadimages.PostedFile.FileName);
    //Save images into Images folder   
    fileuploadimages.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Images/" + filename));
    //Getting dbconnection from web.config connectionstring
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BallinoraDBConnectionString1"].ToString());
    //Open the database connection
    con.Open();
    //Query to insert images path and name into database
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Group_Images(ImageName,ImagePath) values(@ImageName,@ImagePath)", con);
    //Passing parameters to query
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageName", filename);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImagePath", "Images/" + filename);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //Close dbconnection
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("~/Admin.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Is it choking on the space in "4th Year"?

Comment: @J.McCabe I managed to write to the 'Images' folder previously, using different code, which I have now posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Server.MapPath("~/SlideImages)`. Notice the `~/` prefix which forces the mappath to start at the root of the web application.

Then add the file name as the file does not exist yet on disk but you should use `System.IO.Path.Combine` to combine the mapped root website path (and images folder) with the file name.

Also you should check if the directory exists or not. In your screen shot you have content in `Images` so this folder is probably being copied to your destination website path when you deploy. The other one is empty, it might not be created when you deploy your application because there is no content to copy.

Here is the modified code, check if it exists and create it if it does not. You should verify the web application's user context has sufficient privileges to create a directory in the root website directory.

```
var directory = Server.MapPath("~/SlideImages");
if(!System.IO.Directory.Exists(directory))
    System.IO.Directory.Create(directory);

fileuploadimages.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, filename));
```

---

#### Side note

You should wrap any instances that implement `IDisposable` with `using` blocks or make sure that they are disposed of in the dispose method of the containing type. I noticed in your 2nd example you created a `SqlConnection` instance and then called `close` later which is not good practice. Why that is is because if you have an Exception that occurs your SqlConnection, SqlCommand, or anything else that needs to clean up resources will stick around longer than needed which can cause issues later on like exceeding the max number of simultaneous allowed open connections to a Sql Server or not being able to serve an image because there is a lock on the file.